# Identification of two leaders in Hungarian revolution

Tags: identification, hungary, persona

Who are these two figures involved in the revolution in Hungary after the first world war?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Google search revealed that the one on the left is [Sándor Garbai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A1ndor_Garbai). [image]

(from https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Garbai_S%C3%A1ndor_%281919%29_%28cropped%29.jpg)

The one to his right seems kind of similar to an individual named Béla Kun, but I am not fully sure.

[EDIT]: This [Wiki page on Béla Kun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9la_Kun) has [same image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Garbai_Kun.jpg) (from different angle I suppose), and its caption says "Sandor Garbai and Bela Kun, leaders of the Hungarian Soviet Republic, 1919". So I believe he **is** Béla Kun.

Comment: Oh, wow, you can actually see the movie camera from which my frame came in that still shot. That is pretty cool.

Comment: @TylerDurden Oh, yes. I hadn't noticed that!